# how to delete multiple items in graphql?

Tags: graphql, scaphold

Given an array of  ids, how can I write a delete mutation to delete multiple items at the same time?

PS: I'm using a graphql hosted plateform provided by [Scaphoold.io](https://scaphold.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete multiple items at once on Scaphold. But you can run the delete mutation with different IDs in a script perhaps if you have a lot of them.